# Unable to use ForEach for distinct records from coredata

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a table that contains 20 songs from 5 different artists, this number can go up and down , now i want a View where i can display a navigation of these unique singers with their images that are also in table.

So i need only distinct records based on artistname, i query coredata but when i use it in View , i get `Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'`

Now to overcome this i use id:.self, this also does not work.

Now i read and learn that ForEach does not like any TYPE that is not sorted , but i have not been able to find a way around this, can any one kindly suggest any solutions, thanks.

This is how i fetch the unique records from core data

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Artists")
    
    
    init(songLVM: Binding<SongListVM>){

    _songLVM = songLVM
        
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["artistname"]
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
    fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
        
    }
```

Below is the entire file

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ArtistList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Binding var songLVM: SongListVM
    @State var namesFilter = [String]()
    
    
    //-----
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Artists")
    
    
    init(songLVM: Binding<SongListVM>){

    _songLVM = songLVM
        
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["artistname"]
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
    fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
        
    }
    
    
    //-----
    
   
    
    
    var body: some View {
   
        
            List {
               
                ForEach(fetchRequest) { <---- Error here 
                    idx in
                
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ArtistSongs(artistName: idx.artistname ?? "no name", songLVM: $songLVM)) {

                            
                            ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing)  {
                            
                           
                                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: idx.artistImage ?? Data()) ?? UIImage())
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 350, height: 350, alignment: .center)
                                    
                                Text(idx.artistname ?? "no name")
                                   
                                    .font(Font.system(size: 50, design: .rounded))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                           
                            }
                            
                           
                        
                            }
                        
                      
                    }
                }
            

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to do a `forEach` on the "result" of the fetch instead of the "fetch command"?

Comment: @Larme , thanks , do you want me to transfer the artists1 to some other variable and then do a for each item in demo like loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you figure out what your dictionary is, try this in your `ForEach` loop:

```
ForEach(dict.sorted(by: >), id: \.key) { key, value in
    ...
}
```

EDIT1:

```
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Artists.artistname, ascending: true)],
                  animation: .default)
    private var artists: FetchedResults<Artists>

    ...
    
    ForEach(artists, id: \.self) { artist in
      ...
    }
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong but in my code , when i do this -  ForEach(fetchRequest.sorted(by: >), id: \.key) {
                    key, value in , i get multiple errors like Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'NavigationLink<ZStack<_>, ArtistSongs>' conform to 'TableRowContent', Value of type 'NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>' has no member 'sorted' etc, is it that the coredata query is incorrect ?

Comment: updated my answer, with a possible approach.

Comment: Sorry i got it resolved now, thanks a lot, it helps me understand Collections better